# How to get ELMAH to log to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I've been looking around with this question and there are barely any answers.

Previously, we have been using ELMAH to log to a table in Microsoft SQL Server, however we are changing the backend to use MySQL instead(MariaDB specifically).

So all was fine, the errors had been logging to SQL Server. I have installed the ELMAH MySql package and changed the connection strings to use the new MySQL table. However, when an error is thrown, no error gets logged. I'm confused to why this is happening.

It really doesn't help that there are virtually any documentation on this. For example, are you supposed to just install ELMAH.MySQL on its own? Or does it need to go with my previous ELMAH configurations?

ELMAH webconfig:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- TODO: Replace the ****'s with the correct entries -->
    <add name="elmah-mysql" connectionString="server=web01;UserId=root;Password=Tr@nsf0rmers;database=elmah; CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
  </connectionStrings>

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.MySqlErrorLog, Elmah.MySql" connectionStringName="elmah-mysql" />
  </elmah>

<appSettings>
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
    <add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

<httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>

<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
```

Exception handler:

```
public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {
            // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
            if (context.ExceptionHandled)            
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);  
        }
    }
```

It hits this code.

Seriously, what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Right well I managed to get it to work by doing the following. I uninstalled all of my ELMAH references. Reinstalled them, installed the MySQL ELMAH package and then changed the connection strings and it worked. Just like that.

Follow this guide: https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/elmah-a-quick-start-tutorial-and-guide/

And convert to MySQL where he uses SQLite instead.

Comment: which packages did you install? I am having the same issue :)

Comment: @Rolando Elmah.MySQL